# AC current transducer symbol

Tags: ac, current-measurement, transducer

What does the symbol in the red circle mean?

[image: Ac Current Transducer]

([Product page](http://www.eltime.co.uk/product.php/44/AC%20Current%20Transducers.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearly meant to represent a current transformer. The data sheet specifies that the transducers can measure current directly or with a current transformer. The advantage of the current transformer is that it provides isolation between the current source and the current transducer.

Answer (score 2):

It is a current transformer.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_transformer

Answer (score 0):

I THINK it's an isolation transformer.  The product description does say that it can be used directly or with such a transformer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_transformer